# sql server error online for bigrock hosting

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services, web

Error showing on bigrock hosting for asp.net application

> login failed for user ' '

On login link there is login page after entering right credential it gives me the error

> "login failed for user 'shreesa.mdf'"

Bigrock tech support teams fails to resolve this issue. please help to solve this problem.

According to me there is some problems in my web.config file.

I am also adding the code here..

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    </system.web>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Conn" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=shreesa.mdf;Integrated Security=False; User Id=saachlrw; Password=******;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Your DataSource in Connectionstring is "localhost". Please check.

Comment: I have changed it to sever ip address but same error giving

Answer (score 0):

Modify your **Connectionstring** in this way:

**Before**

```
connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=shreesa.mdf;Integrated Security=False; User Id=saachlrw; Password=******;"
```

**After**

```
connectionString="Server=localhost;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|shreesa.mdf;Database=yourdbname;Integrated Security=False; User Id=saachlrw; Password=******;"
```

[SQL Server connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)